# DB2 backup file deletion

Tags: db2, database-backups

My DB2 backups are starting to take up too much space, and I'd like to start pruning some of the older files. In the past I had simply deleted some files, but that led to some issues when trying to use one of the backup files (unfortunately the details escape me).

I read [here](http://www.dba-db2.com/2013/08/manage-db2-backups-retention-policy.html) that I can get DB2 to manage this. I did the following:

`db2 update db cfg for db_name using AUTO_DEL_REC_OBJ ON
    db2 update db cfg for db_name using NUM_DB_BACKUPS 6
    db2 update db cfg for db_name using REC_HIS_RETENTN 21`

Our backups run twice weekly, so I was thinking I would save 3 weeks worth. After setting these values, I ran a backup:

`db2 backup db db_name user username using password online to file_path include logs without prompting`

The backup ran correctly and created a new backup file, but none of the existing files were deleted (I have backups more than 21 days old).

As per [this link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.config.doc/doc/r0051456.html) I expected the Auto Delete to occur at the time I ran the backup. My LOGARCHMETH1 is set to USEREXIT.

My questions are:

Why did my previous files not get removed (and what do I need to change to get them to be removed automatically)?

Can I safely remove log files by simply deleting them from the filesystem?

Comment: Does the history file contain records of backups older than 21 days? Does your user exit program support deletion of logs?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by the "history file" - but I do have backup files older than 21 days.

Comment: The recovery history file is described in one of the two links you posted. You can list its contents with the command `list history backup...`

Comment: Thanks, I'm still not used to db2 management. The results of the list history backup command show dates from Feb 10, 2016. Also, I've been reading up on the USEREXIT and it seems that I've set the value, but there is no associated program 'installed' (if that's the right terminology). Are backup files that are NOT listed in the results of the "list history backup" safe to delete?

Comment: What's in the history file has no relation to what's safe to delete. I asked about the history file because only the backup images known to DB2 via that file would be automatically purged. Since you're saying you have images that _are_ listed in the history file and still aren't purged, there must be some other issue with your configuration.